# Equivalentes de res.status en express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

mi pregunta es que si es lo mismo colocar

```
res.send({ok:true});
res.status(200).send({ok:true});
res.json({ok:true});
```

Es decir, si por defecto el `send` envia el status 200 y si es lo mismo colocar `send` que colocar `json`. Y si no son lo mismo alguien puede decirme la diferencia entre los tres

Comment: Te recomiendo este artículo de  [fullstack-developer.academy](https://fullstack-developer.academy/res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express/)

Comment: La duda se fue leyendo este articulo. https://fullstack-developer.academy/res-json-vs-res-send-vs-res-end-in-express/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `res.status` cambia el código de estado http, a menos que lo hayas ejecutado antes con un valor diferente, el valor que tendrá por defecto es `200`. Lo puedes saber si ejecutas:

```
const http = require('http');

console.log(http.ServerResponse.prototype.statusCode);
```

El framework solo crea un [wrapper](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L42) alrededor de esta [propiedad](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L66) que es la que se utiliza para cambiar el código a la hora de enviar la respuesta. Cuando la ejecutas sólo cambias el valor de una propiedad, nada más.

En cuanto a `res.json` y `res.send` son casi identicos, de hecho, ambos se llaman entre ellos en [determinadas circunstancias](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L158).

```
switch (typeof chunk) {
  // string defaulting to html
  case 'string':
    if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
      this.type('html')
    }
    break;
  case 'boolean':
  case 'number'
  case 'object':
    if (chunk === null) {
      chunk = '';
    } else if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
      if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
        this.type('bin');
      }
    } else {
      return this.json(chunk);
    }
    break;
}
```

Este es parte del código fuente de `res.send` y como vez llama a `res.json` si el tipo que mandas en la respuesta es `number`, `boolean` u `object`.

```
if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
  this.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

return this.send(body);
```

Este es parte del código del `res.json` que a su vez llama a `res.send` siempre.

Imagino que ahora tienes la duda ¿Por qué no se forma un ciclo infinito?

Pues porque cuando llamas a `res.send` este convierte el valor dependiendo de su tipo. En los casos donde le toca llamar a `json` usa `return this.json(chunk);` para hacer recursividad y luego vuelve a ejecutarse ya como un `string` por lo que no vuelve a entrar en esa parte del código y se ejecutan tareas como generación de e-tags y cálculo de `Content-Length`.

En los otros casos donde llamas a `res.json` este sólo se limita a establecer el `Content-Type`, convertir a `string` el resultado y procede con `res.send`.

En conclusión, usa `res.json` cuando sepas que estás mandando objetos o tu cliente **siempre** espera recibir `json` pues podrías terminar enviando el `Content-Type` incorrecto y tener resultados inesperados.

En cuanto a diferencias visibles intenta enviar un `null` u otros tipos que no sean objetos y podrás observar que en algunos casos los resultados son diferentes así que tu código deberá manejar esos casos de manera diferente.